# how to send array parameter using alamofire

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to make a post request with a body array in swift using Alamofire

postman like 
[image]

and here my code

```
class func storeEventContact(_ id:String, type_contact:String, user_id: Int, firstname:String, lastname: String,completionHandler:RequestCompletionHandler?){
    let url = "\(Endpoints.BASE)\(Endpoints.INVITE_STORE)"

    let params:NSMutableDictionary? = ["id": id,
                  "type_contact":type_contact,
                  "contacts": ["user_id" : user_id, "firstname" : firstname, "lastname" : lastname]]
    self.postRequest(url: url, parameters: params as? [String : Any]) { (result, error) in
        self.postRequest(url: url, parameters: params as? [String : Any]) { (result, error) in
            if error != nil{
                completionHandler?(result, error)
                return
            }
            let baseResponse = Mapper<BaseResponse>().map(JSONObject: result)
            if !baseResponse!.status{
                completionHandler?(baseResponse, error)
                return
            }
            completionHandler?(result, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue in passing array as parameter???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to define an array, you are almost there, just need an extra set of `[]` in your dictionary.

```
let params = ["id": id,
              "type_contact":type_contact,
              "contacts": [
              [
                   "user_id": user_id, 
                   "firstname": firstname, 
                   "lastname": lastname
              ]]]
```